# L'inversion et le pronom de rappel

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, questions, pronom-de-reprise

Dans mon livre de français, il y a la phrase « À quelle heure commence la présentation pour moi ? ». Il y a bien sûr l'inversion, mais avec un nom comme sujet, faut-il utiliser un pronom de rappel, comme « À quelle heure la présentation commence-t-elle pour moi ? » ?

Comment: Hors sujet mais il faut avoir conscience qu'à l'oral, l'inversion se fait de plus en plus rare. La manière la plus courante de poser cette question en français parlé courant est une combinaison de : (1) `Pour moi`, (2) `elle commence à quelle heure` ou `à quelle heure elle commence` et (3) `la présentation` où les trois blocs peuvent être placés dans n'importe quel ordre en fonction de ce qui veut être mis en avant.

Comment: @jlliagre : Hors sujet aussi et oui pour tes suggestions plus usuelles mais je me demande si *"Quand est-ce qu'elle commence..."* voire *à quelle heure est-ce qu'elle commence...* ne serait pas encore plus usuel.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je ne sais pas mais ce sont effectivement des tournures très courantes aussi. On pourrait y ajouter le plus relâché : *c'est à quelle heure qu'elle commence...*

Answer (score 2):

Dans ton exemple précis, il n'y a pas de *"il faut"*. On écrit comme on veut.

---

**À la nuance importante rappelée par Laure en commentaires que s'il s'agit d'un exercice scolaire, les consignes de l'exercice / les directives données dans le cours doivent prévaloir.**

---

*À quelle heure commence la présentation ?* est grammaticalement correct, on dirait cette construction : Interrogation directe simple.

*À quelle heure la présentation commence-t-elle* est aussi grammaticalement correct, on dirait cette construction : Interrogation directe complexe.
(le sujet (*présentation*) reste devant le verbe et il est repris par le pronom personnel (*elle*) après le verbe)

Dans le cas général, les deux styles conviennent également, on pourra distinguer :

- Le cas où l'interrogation est introduite par un mot interrogatif **complément**. (***Quand*** ma présentation commence-t-elle ?) On tiendra alors la complexe pour plus correcte.
- Le cas ou l'interrogation est introduite par un mot interrogatif **sujet**. (***Qui*** de nous deux ira à cette présentation ?) La complexe, bien que très correcte aussi sera néanmoins tenue pour un signe d'affectation. Mieux vaut donc l'éviter.
- Quand le mot interrogatif est sujet ou attribut (***Qui*** tes potes ont-ils...). C'est peut être le seul cas ou la complexe est largement préférable pour nécessités de disambigüation.

Comment: +1 avec bémol : **si** il s'agit d'un exercice scolaire il vaut mieux/il est recommandé d'appliquer les règles pour entrer dans le cadre de de la notation scolaire, on ne sait pas quel niveau de langue attend le professeur.  Quand le sujet est un nom  on utilise soit l'expression « est-ce que » soit un pronom de rappel. Donc peut-être ajouter que l'interrogation simple est familière  ? Mais très courante et habituelle à l'oral

Comment: @Laure : Tu as très raison, avertissement inclus dans la réponse. Merci à toi.

Comment: Merci pour ton explication ! Dans ton premier cas, qu'est-ce que « mot interrogatif complément » veut dire ? Est-ce que « À quelle heure » aussi un mot interrogatif complément ?

Comment: @seismatica : Oui absolument. Quel (quelle) est effectivement un mot interrogatif. Même précédé par une préposition (à, pour, de, chez...) Donc oui absolument, puisqu'il est ici CCT, ta phrase correspond au premier des cas envisagés dans le cas général dans lequel on peut dire que la complexe sera tenue pour plus correcte.

Answer (score 1):

Dans *Le Bon Usage*, XIVe ed. n° 371 où il est question des *redondances habituelles*, ce pronom dit de rappel est aussi appelé un *pronom conjoint*.

> Redondances habituelles.
>   a) Sous la forme du pronom personnel conjoint.
>   1 ° Dans des cas où le pronom personnel sujet (ainsi que ce et on) connaît régulièrement l'inversion, les sujets d'une autre nature gardent leur place ordinaire, mais sont repris par un pronom personnel conjoint placé immédiatement après le verbe.
>   • Dans la phrase interrogative : Votre père reviendra-f-IL lundi ? (Parallèlement à : Reviendra-t-il lundi ?).
>   • Dans la phrase énonciative commençant par peut-être, sans doute,
>   etc. : Peut-être votre père reviendra-t-IL lundi.

La reprise par le pronom de rappel est donc nécessaire d'après le n° 1 puisque le sujet est un nom et qu'il garde dans cette interrogation sa place normale (avant le verbe).